# Refreshing a block using AJAX

Tags: 7, blocks, javascript, flags

I am trying to apply the example from [the Flag API page][1] to refresh a block dynamically via AJAX. I am looking into customised jQuery code because my block is created via a module, not a view.

I have implemented the callback in the .module file and it works. It is when I try to copy `blockExistsOnPage()` where I fail. It talks about a component module which is necessary for the execution of the code, but this module is obsolete for drupal 7. I think that I stumble on the definition of `var domId`. This is my JavaScript code.

```
(function ($) {
 $(document).bind('flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate', function(event, data) {
   alert('Object #' + data.contentId + ' (of type ' +
   data.contentType + ') has been ' + data.flagStatus +
   ' using flag "' + data.flagName + '"');

    if (data.flagName == 'myflag') {

        if (blockExistsOnPage('mymodule', 'mymodule_blockid')) {
            refreshBlock('mymodule', 'mymodule_blockid');
        }
    }
  });

// Attempt at refreshing the block
function blockExistsOnPage(module_name, block_id) {
  var domId = module_name + '/' + block_id;
  return $('#'+domId).length != 0;
}


function refreshBlock(module_name, block_id) {
  var domId = module_name + '/' + block_id;
  $.get(base_url + 'node/' + $nodeid + '/' + block_id, null, function(newHtml)  {
    // Replace the old block with the new one.
    var domElement = $(newHtml).insertAfter('#'+domId);
    $('#'+domId).remove();
    if (Drupal.attachBehaviors) {
       Drupal.attachBehaviors(domElement);
    }
 });
}
```

edit: I am trying to use a $.ajax request instead. It seems cleaner, but I am struggling to get my relative address of the type node/[nid]/module_name/block_id. Should I modify the block_id in the menu hook? Or should I find a way to create a url in the jquery:

module hook menu:
    function get_involved_menu() {

```
// Ajax Callback. Returns updated content of block
$items['block_id'] = array (
 'title' => 'Content of module_name block',
 'page callback' => 'module_name_createcontent',
 'access arguments' => array ('access content'),
 'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );

return $items;
}
```

jquery:
    $(document).bind('flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate', function(event, data) {

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'module_name/block_id',
     success: function (data){
        $('div.get-involved-divblock').html(data);
     }
   });
 });
```

the code below returns an empty block. If I am on node '57', and I put instead

```
 url: '57/module_name/block_id',
```

Then it returns the content. How can I make it a relative path? How do I obtain the node id in the jquery?

Comment: The domID here refers to the *unique* ID of the block. This block ID is generated from the module_name + block ID. if your module defines the block, check the html source to find the `id` attribute of the block.

Comment: Hello Ayesh,in my case, the module is 'get_involved' and the block id is 'get_involved_block', which I had defined. I do not seem to get anything out of the 'return $('#'+domId).length != 0;' line. Is my command ok? I am no expert in jQuery...

Comment: The problem is that node/[nid]/[block_id] is not a valid path, in plain Drupal; that is probably something the missing module provided.

Comment: Thanks Kiamlaluno. I am looking into getting the right path...

Comment: I have used GUE's answer from this page: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78662/how-to-get-the-drupal-node-id-from-within-jquery-javascript, and it loads something in my block. But currently, it is loading the whole page! Not just my block...

Answer (score 1):

depending on how your module is setting up the block, you could look into [Block Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_refresh):

> Block Refresh allows an administrator to configure a block to refresh
>   it's content via 3 different methods: automatically via a timer (eg
>   every 30 seconds) , manually via a 'refresh' link, and once on page
>   load.
>
> Block Refresh uses jQuery/AJAX so the refresh happens
>   "behind-the-scenes".
>
> Block refresh can be handy to serve fresh content in certain blocks on
>   otherwise cached pages. You can opt to bypass drupal's cache for the
>   refresh callbacks for each block.

**Edit**

I just ran into this exact problem and developed a simple little approach that works nicely:

- using [Block Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_refresh)

  - set up each of the blocks you want to refresh as manual - this would normally cause a link to appear in each block allowing a click refresh
- create some css to hide the ugly links:

  ```
  .block-refresh-button
  {
      display:none;
  }
  ```
- then add a simple jQuery click to force block refresh to do all the work for you - this can be modified appropriately as necessary:

  ```
  jQuery(".flag-wrapper").click(function()
  {
      jQuery(".block-refresh-button").each(function()
      {
          jQuery(this).click();
      });
  });
  ```

I found this will refresh ALL blocks on the page set up with block refresh, including Views.

Comment: Thanks Geoff,I tried that module, but it does not allow to trigger a refresh based on a flag event.

Comment: I added an edit